# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction); not working in reactjs

Tags: cordova, reactjs, geolocation

I am quite new in reactjs and cordova
I am attaching

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction,errorFunction);
function successFunction(position) 
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    geolocation=lat+" "+lng;
}

getContent: function () 
{
    var feedbackObj = Store.getData();
    if(!feedbackObj)
    {
        actions.getFormData();
        return(
            <div className="gclass form">
            <Loader />
            </div>
        );
    }
    var className = "hide";
    if(feedbackObj["receive_update"] === "1")
    {
        className = "feedbackUserDetails";
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction1, errorFunction1);

    function successFunction1(position)
    {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        geolocation=lat+" "+lng;
        console.log(geolocation);
        console.log("ABC");
    }
    function errorFunction1()
    {
        alert("Geocoder failed");
    }
    return(
    <div className="gclass form">
    <TextArea name={"incident_title"} isRequired={true} limit={2000} onSave={this._onSave} id={"incident_title"} defaultvalue={feedbackObj["incident_title"]}/>
    <TextArea name={"incident_desc"} isRequired={true} limit={2000} onSave={this._onSave} id={"incident_desc"} defaultvalue={feedbackObj["incident_desc"]}/>
    <Calendar name={"incident_date"} isRequired={true} id={"incident_date"} onSave={this._onSave} defaultvalue={feedbackObj["incident_date"]} />
    <TextBox name={"incident_location"} isRequired={true} id={"incident_location"} onSave={this._onSave} defaultvalue="abc" />
    <Attach name={"upload_attachment"} id={"upload_attachment"} onSave={this._onSave} defaultvalue={feedbackObj["upload_attachment"]} />
    </div>        
    );
}
```

to my react jsx file. But it is not call backing to any of my function (successFunction or errorFunction)

get content is called here

```
  getInitialState: function () {
return {content:this.getContent()};
```

}

do I need to add some require for it ?

Comment: How are you calling this in react file , can you share some code ?

Comment: @Sachin I have added few things

Comment: And how are you calling getContent ?

Please furnish all the details relevant to question. Check the guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Sachin sorry for not being very clear. i have added how am i calling getContent.

Comment: and what is the URL you are using for this app ? 
localhost ?

Comment: No its one  amazon server @Sachin

Comment: please accept the below answer if it solves your problem. This will be helpful to others if they face similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCurrentPosition() no longer works on insecure origins in Chrome. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Comment: but its should work on other browser and i am usinbg reactjs in cordova for mobile app